# Microsoft Access as SQL Server Front End. Will it fire Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, triggers, bulkinsert

I need a fast front end solution for my SQL Server.

I planned to create a few Access forms that will allow users to enter and edit data, as my user don't have any sort of training in how to use Access.

My only concern is that the data they enter in Access will not fire triggers that are in place on my SQL Server. I have tried in that past to do this and each time data enters into table and the trigger never fires. Is there a way to enable this through Access?

Comment: Correct. Microsoft Access.
Triggers are enabled and fire fine when using native SQL inserts and VB.net applications that SQLBulkCopy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have placed a trigger on a table for a specific operation (e.g. AFTER INSERT) it should fire regardless of the application that issues the queries (e.g. MS ACCESS, Sql Management Studio, .NET App).

However, a trigger might not fire if:

- it is disabled
- another trigger is placed on the table, it fires before the trigger of interest and it has an error (this will lead to the transaction being rolled back and not running any subsequent trigger)
- you are performing [WRITETEXT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/writetext-transact-sql)s ([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187834(v=sql.105).aspx)) or `TRUNCATE`s
- if bulk inserts does not specify `FIRE_TRIGGERS` option ([source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx))

Also check that trigger is properly defined for the type of operation you are actually performing (e.g. `INSTEAD OF DELETE` to catch `UPDATE`s)

Comment: Thank you for the well written answer.